# Using Typescript to force generic constraint for interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 interface declarations :

```
interface IStore    { }
interface SomethingElse     { a: number;}
```

And 2 classes which implements  each:

```
class AppStoreImplemetion implements IStore 
 { }

class SomethingImplementation  implements SomethingElse
 {
    a: 4;
 }
```

I want my method to be given the return type as a constraint of "must be `IStore`"  , so I did this:

```
class Foo {

    selectSync<T extends IStore>( ):  T
        {
        return <T>{/* omitted*/ };    // I set the return type(`T`) when invoking
        }
}
```

OK

Testing :

This works as expected :

```
new Foo().selectSync<AppStoreImplemetion>();
```

But this also works - *not* as expected :

```
new Foo().selectSync<SomethingImplementation>();
```

**Question:**

How can I force my method to accept a return type which must implement `IStore` ?

[**Online demo**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IStore%20%20%20%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20SomethingElse%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20a%3A%20number%3B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20AppStoreImplemetion%20implements%20IStore%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SomethingImplementation%20%20implements%20SomethingElse%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%204%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20selectSync%3CT%20extends%20IStore%3E(%20)%3A%20%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%3CT%3E%7B%2F*%20omitted*%2F%20%7D%3B%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Foo().selectSync%3CAppStoreImplemetion%3E()%3B%0D%0Anew%20Foo().selectSync%3CSomethingImplementation%3E()%3B)

Comment: You cant. Typescript has duck typing. However i think typescript would benefit from unduckable types, so if you request it as a feature, i will support you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is Typescript usses structural typing to determine type compatibility, so the interface `IStore` which is empty, is compatible with any other type, including `SomethingElse`

The only way to simulate nominal typing (the kind you have in C#/Java etc.) is to add a field that makes the interface incompatible with other interfaces. You don't actually have to use the field, you just have to declare it to ensure incompatibility:

```
interface IStore { 
    __isStore: true // Field to ensure incompatibility
}
interface SomethingElse { a: number; }

class AppStoreImplemetion implements IStore { 
    __isStore!: true // not used, not assigned just there to implement IStore
}

class SomethingImplementation implements SomethingElse {
    a = 4;
}

class Foo {

    selectSync<T extends IStore>(): T {
        return <T>{/* omitted*/ };   
    }
}

new Foo().selectSync<AppStoreImplemetion>();
new Foo().selectSync<SomethingImplementation>(); // This will be an error
```

Note that any class that has `__isStore` will be compatible regardless of weather it explicitly implements `IStore`, again due to the fact that Typescript uses structure to determine compatibility, so this is valid:

```
class SomethingImplementation implements SomethingElse {
    a = 4;
    __isStore!: true 
}
new Foo().selectSync<SomethingImplementation>(); // now ok
```

In practice `IStore` will probably have more methods, so such accidental compatibility should be rare enough.

Just as a side note, private fields ensure 100% incompatibility for unrelated classes, so if it is possible to make `IStore` an abstract class with a private field. This can ensure no other class is accidentally compatible:

```
abstract class IStore { 
    private __isStore!: true // Field to ensure incompatibility
}
interface SomethingElse { a: number; }

class AppStoreImplemetion extends IStore { 

}
class Foo {

    selectSync<T extends IStore>(): T {
        return <T>{/* omitted*/ };   
    }
}

new Foo().selectSync<AppStoreImplemetion>(); // ok 

class SomethingImplementation implements SomethingElse {
    private __isStore!: true;
    a = 10;
}
new Foo().selectSync<SomethingImplementation>(); // an error even though we have the same private since it does not extend IStore
```

Comment: Sorry but what's that  `!:` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I use `strict` when I compile, so I got an error that the fields was not initialized `!` tells the compiler not to worry about the uninitialized field.

Comment: Oh. TIL. Thanks.

Comment: @RoyiNamir also added the option for 100% incompatibility with abstract classes and a private field. Hope it helps, good luck